# What should the missing number be?

Tags: number-sequence

What number should be put instead of '?'?

```
 9    4    3     3  

26    8    6    22  

28    ?    7    21
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answer is

> 7

As, the recipe to find the missing number is

> Multiply 2nd term , 3rd term and then subtract 4th term to get the first term

That Is, for example

> 26 = (8×6) - 22.